# Can't log in to chat despite switching browsers and clearing cookies and cache

Tags: support, chat, openid

Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit

tried chrome and firefox

Used OpenID cannot log in to chat.

**UPDATE**

the thing that worked for me was

> There is also a secondary option; log
>   in to your preferred Stack Exchange
>   site, and edit the URL (usually at the
>   top of your browser) to http://{your
>   stackexchange
>   site.com}/users/chat-stackexchange-login,
>   for example:
>   https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login.

This line should be placed **ABOVE** the line on contacting meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: can you try again from chrome incognito, perhaps its a cookie issue?

Comment: What does http://chat.stackexchange.com/help say?

Comment: The secondary option is a workaround that was mainly put in place to give IE7 users a chance to use the chat. Please tell us what the test results on the page were.

Comment: @balpha All ok were the results I got in that page.

Answer (score 1):

For all chat related login issues, refer to

https://chat.stackexchange.com/help

first