# Why am I not able to chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

I have 58 reputation on Stack Overflow, but I am not able to talk in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com).

Why is this?

Comment: lets check http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10629/agarwal

Comment: I got editbox and send button beside that. when i type something and press enter then the msg is not displayed in chat room and beside send button and fixed font button.

Comment: @AgarwalShankar

Comment: Probably try by refreshing one or two times might be a issue with slow net connection

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81627/155826

Comment: @Naseer seems to be problem with your browser or your net. coz i was able to login to your account and also chat from my browser. try at your side by different browser or refreshing or clearing the caches.

Comment: @Naseerkhan are you using Firefox ?

Comment: I am using Chrome. Here I found the solution i.e network problem and also my system problem. When i login in another system then i am able to chat. Thank u